# Rails controller not decoding urls. Is this right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a request as
http://localhost:3000/templates/2.jpg?template_usage=0

and everything works fine.
But when I make the request as 
http://localhost:3000/templates/2.jpg%3Ftemplate_usage%3D0

I receive an 
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
because the controller understands that the format is jpg?template_usage=0

Is this the expected behaviour. How could I work around this?

This is the controller code

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
... return html
        end
        format.jpg do 
 ... return jpg
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Easy, just don't escape the characters in the URL. If you do escape them, your result is exactly what is expected as you specifically escaped the boundary characters so they are not interpreted in their normal way.

Comment: I am not escaping them. Some sites include links to us and they escape them there (reasons unknown) and then when users click they are directed to our site and get an error.

Comment: It sounds like the other site is incorrectly processing the url to your site.  How do they get onto that other site?  Do you submit them via a form or something?

Comment: Sites are just crawling and adding links to resources. So it is automatically. My concern is probably more on the fact that there is an exception each time this method is called. It seems that working with incorrect urls is not an exceptional situation and I would like to deal with this without throwing and exception

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly right and it's exactly the purpose of escaping characters.... if you want a `?` to be passed as data not as the start of parameters you would escape it.

If for some reason you must have the escaped characters passed then you'd have to parse the format yourself but this is a code smell.

```
def show
  my_format = params[:format].split('?').first
  case my_format
  when 'jpg'
    ...
```

Note that you'd also need to take any arguments passed and parse them yourself.